# Estoy intentando hacer un test para un flow que emite una instancia de Unit en kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-corrutinas

Tengo un viewModel que tiene varios channels que se emiten como flow que se consumen en la vista de la siguiente manera.

```
  private val _goToRegister = Channel<Unit>()
  val goToRegister = _goToRegister.receiveAsFlow()
```

Mi pregunta es que quiero hacer los tests para ese viewModel, y no se como hacer para hacer los asserts, hasta ahora estoy recibiendo una excepción de corrutina

**Coroutine "kotlinx.coroutines.test runner#3":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@405f2efa, state: SUSPENDED
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$workRunner$1.invokeSuspend**

El test que estoy invocando me está quedando así:

```
 fun `WHEN User has not logged in THEN goToRegister AND goToWalker AND goToOwner should not be called AND goToRegister should be called`() =
        runTest {
                every { userRepository.signIn(any()) } returns flow {
                    emit(Result.success(null))
                }

                mViewModel.checkSignedIn()
                val unidad = mViewModel.goToRegister.collect()
                assertEquals(Unit,unidad)
        }
```

con la regla de UnconfinedTestDispatcher() creada:

```
    open fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(UnconfinedTestDispatcher())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar, usando la librería turbine, de manera bastante sencilla, al final los tests quedan mas o menos así:

```
    @Test
    fun `WHEN User has authenticated AND userIsRegistered returns false then goToRegister should be called`() =
        runTest {
                coEvery { userRepository.signIn(any()) } returns Result.success(null)
                coEvery { userRepository.userIsRegistered(any()) } returns Result.success(false)
                every { authenticator.isAuthenticated(any()) } returns flow {
                    emit(userDummy)
                }

                mViewModel.goToRegister.test {
                    mViewModel.checkSignedIn()
                    val unidad = awaitItem()
                    assertEquals(Unit, unidad)
                }
        }
```